# Can I set a specific drive (e.g,"D:\") as a default directory for showOpenFilePicker?

Tags: javascript, file, directory, file-system-access-api

We have a Java (JSP) web application and I want (well, the client) wants when they upload a file , based on a specific condition , the file picker to open directly in the D drive root directory. Also when they download a file, the file to be downloaded automatically by default in the same D (USB) drive (not universally through browser settings of course).

I know that this is not possible due to security reasons but I recently saw about this File System Access API and I am trying to understand what is possible.

Well, apparently we can use

```
async function fileOpen() {
            const fileHandle = await window.showOpenFilePicker({
                startIn: 'documents'
            });
        }
```

but in the `startIn` property whenever I try setting `D:\` or anything other than the `WellKnownDirectories` I get the error:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'showOpenFilePicker' on 'Window': Failed to read the 'startIn' property from 'FilePickerOptions': The provided value 'D:\' is not a valid enum value of type WellKnownDirectory.`

So is something like that possible? The file picker that opens from the `<input type=file>` doesn't support setting any value for the default directory so this is why I am looking at the file system access api.

Keep in mind that this is a controlled environment and the existence of the `D:` drive is ensured

Comment: Have you tried a browser extension? I don't if it's possible, but I would check it. The extension API provides many more possibilities. Do you have documentation for the `startIn` property? I can't find it.

Comment: You can find info here : https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/#ask-the-user-to-pick-a-file-to-read

No I don't want to try browser extensions as this requires installation in so many client's PCs. It has to be done programmatically

Comment: “this is a controlled environment”—not by you, as it seems. If the user wants the downloads’ default directory to be `D:`, the user has to configure their browser accordingly. It’s part of the controlled environment. And a file picker is not an automatic download anyway… Besides that, this doesn’t seem to be a Java question at all, so the `java` tag is not appropriate.

Comment: @Holger it's not that the user wants the download directory to be universally the D drive. Based on a specific condition , they want the file picker to automatically open in the D drive when they upload a file, the same when they download. I know that in the browser setting you can specify the default Downloads directory but that is not exactly what the want. The Java tag was just because this is a Java web app . So to your knowledge is this something that can't be achieved by JS alone using the File System Access API?

Comment: Well, you already wrote “I know that this is not possible due to security reasons”, so our knowledge is the same. I do not expect to find something in the specification saying “this (oddly specific) example contradicting our understanding of security (also) doesn’t work”.

Comment: This had to do mainly with the functionality of  `input type='file'` which doesn't allow you to do anything at all with the file picker. The new API gives you more customization options and this is where my question lies. If , someway, lets you decide a default upload directory/drive

Comment: Regardless of how you phrase your question, the fundamental problem persists: nobody can show you a proof that something doesn’t exist. You already found out that the `startIn` property only allows enum constants of the speaking type `WellKnownDirectory`. The new API might have more flexibility, but the fundamental principle doesn’t change, you are not supposed to know whether a path `D:` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do with `showOpenFilePicker`/`showSaveFilePicker` (i.e. without requesting acess to directories) is keeping the same directory between pickers:

1. You *can't* request initial path in `showOpenFilePicker`, so the first time you open file picker user have to navigate do `D:/` themselves.
   (you may provide `WellKnownDirectory`("documents"/...) `startIn`) to chose where user starts from
2. The *second* time you open file picker, you may request browser open file picker in the same location by provoding it the same `id`

```
await showOpenFilePicker({ id:"thisGonnaBeDDrive" })
// this opens default directory (socuments or whatever)
// user opens `D:/foo/myfile.bar`
await showOpenFilePicker({ id:"thisGonnaBeDDrive" })
// this opens *the same* directory used last time - `D:/foo/`
await showSaveFilePicker({ id:"thisGonnaBeDDrive" })
// this opens *the same* directory used last time - `D:/foo/`
```

3. Alternatively, you can use the FileSystemHandle you got to open file picker in the same location

```
let [handle] = await showOpenFilePicker()
// user opens `D:/foo/myfile.bar`
showOpenFilePicker({ startIn: handle })
// this opens directory of *the handle* - `D:/foo/`
```

`startIn` handle has a priority over `id`
`id` has a priority over `WellKnownDirectory`(`"documents"`/...) `startIn`

Answer (score 1):

The startIn parameter of the showOpenFilePicker function in JavaScript can **only be set to a WellKnownDirectory**.

**This limitation is in place for security reasons**, as it ensures a secure and consistent user experience. By restricting the parameter to well-known directories, potential security risks are prevented, and users can easily navigate to commonly used directories. Allowing unrestricted access to any directory could potentially lead to malicious activities.